# Kernel Panic on 2014 Mac mini, Mojave

Tags: mac, hard-drive, crash, mac-mini, kernel-panic

So I got error codes many months ago, which I was told were warnings, and my computer ended up having a faulty hard drive and it gave me a prohibited sign. I recently paid $150 to get the hard drive replaced, and approximately 3 days in, I get another one. This time it happened when I opened up the program "FL Studio" for music, and I don't know if this is a reoccurring theme, but it always used to happen before also. Specifically FL Studio. It's either it would shut my computer off with a kernel panic as soon as I open it, or it would shut off about 20 minutes of use into it. What do I do? Was it a hard drive error? I read the report and it said "Fault CPU" and I don't know what I means. I need help here please

```
    `Anonymous UUID:       B438765C-6993-D51B-4B11-BD4EA970B944

     Tue Oct 20 01:03:19 2020

    *** Panic Report ***
    panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801c4dbadd): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9ce07edd, type 14=page                   fault, registers:
    CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff913ddb8000, CR3: 0x0000000020355000, CR4:  0x00000000001626e0
    RAX: 0x000000000000a5a0, RBX: 0xffffff7f9e6b8fc8, RCX: 0x000000000000e696, RDX: 0x0000000000011000
    RSP: 0xffffff913da93cdc, RBP: 0xffffff913da93ce0, RSI: 0xffffff812929ba58, RDI: 0xffffff913ddada58
    R8:  0x0000000000001fa0, R9:  0xffffff913ddada60, R10: 0xffffff812929ba60, R11: 0x0000000000010ffe
    R12: 0x0000000000002b4b, R13: 0xffffff802e686d00, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff802e686d00
    RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f9ce07edd, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
    Fault CR2: 0xffffff913ddb8000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 1

    Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
    0xffffff913da937a0 : 0xffffff801c3ae6ed 
    0xffffff913da937f0 : 0xffffff801c4ea185 
    0xffffff913da93830 : 0xffffff801c4db8ba 
    0xffffff913da938a0 : 0xffffff801c35bb40 
    0xffffff913da938c0 : 0xffffff801c3ae107 
    0xffffff913da939e0 : 0xffffff801c3adf53 
    0xffffff913da93a50 : 0xffffff801c4dbadd 
    0xffffff913da93bc0 : 0xffffff801c35bb40 
    0xffffff913da93be0 : 0xffffff7f9ce07edd 
    0xffffff913da93ce0 : 0xffffff7f9e6b8ee4 
    0xffffff913da93d00 : 0xffffff7f9e68c457 
    0xffffff913da93d60 : 0xffffff7f9ce04db3 
    0xffffff913da93db0 : 0xffffff7f9ce04b1a 
    0xffffff913da93dd0 : 0xffffff7f9ce0483e 
    0xffffff913da93e20 : 0xffffff7f9cdff5bf 
    0xffffff913da93e90 : 0xffffff7f9cdfbb4f 
    0xffffff913da93ec0 : 0xffffff801c3ed885 
    0xffffff913da93f40 : 0xffffff801c3ed425 
    0xffffff913da93fa0 : 0xffffff801c35b0ce 
    Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily(206.5)[63F5D76B-9DD5-3740-9415-798E8DCB52FC]@0xffffff7f9cdf1000->0xffffff7f9ce2ffff
        dependency: com.apple.vecLib.kext(1.2.0)[154A1DE0-6A35-3208-B356-1E5F49868336]@0xffffff7f9cd21000
     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio(315.6)[2AE2AE3D-78BF-32E1-A9E5-4C921D0AEDFA]@0xffffff7f9e672000->0xffffff7f9e6d7fff
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties(1.2)[B7BBAFAC-C52A-361B-AB26-1ED5F0307499]@0xffffff7f9da65000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BFDEB8D4-50FE-3DDB-87B7-F6A504393830]@0xffffff7f9cc95000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily(206.5)[63F5D76B-9DD5-3740-9415-798E8DCB52FC]@0xffffff7f9cdf1000
        dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice(1.2)[7B91C916-590C-3850-BE30-8B73C1B830EC]@0xffffff7f9d49f000
        dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice(1.2)[ABDA1D73-0350-3F07-84A1-D51E51AD6F33]@0xffffff7f9d4a7000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[BD06015A-414D-34DF-BE36-7B9034D7360D]@0xffffff7f9d41d000

    BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

    Mac OS version:
    18G103

    Kernel version:
    Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-  4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
    Kernel UUID: C41337A1-0EC3-3896-A954-A1F85E849D53
    Kernel slide:     0x000000001c000000
    Kernel text base: 0xffffff801c200000
    __HIB  text base: 0xffffff801c100000
    System model name: Macmini7,1 (Mac-35C5E08120C7EEAF)

    System uptime in nanoseconds: 35074242423818
    last loaded kext at 25719405411177: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9f9dc000, size 28672)
    last unloaded kext at 25974875911306: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9f9dc000, size 28672)
    loaded kexts:
    com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
    com.waves.driver.soundgrid  10.0.10
    com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.50.12
    com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.50.12
    com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
    com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
    com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
    com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.14d3
    com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.9
    com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
    com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.25.11
    com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
    com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   12.1.0
    com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.54
    com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
    com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  12.1.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
    com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  354
    com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
    com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
    com.apple.BootCache 40
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
    com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
    com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.7
    com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
    com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.3
    com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
    com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.260.5
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
    com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   201
    com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
    com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.50.12
    com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 760.6
    com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   740.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
    com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
    com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.54
    com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    528
    com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530.51
    com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.50.12
    com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.54
    com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.54
    com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
    com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
    com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.50.12
    com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.14
    com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.66
    com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.6.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
    com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
    com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.14d3
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.14d3
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.14d3
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.14d3
    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  315.6
    com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
    com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
    com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
    com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.6.9
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.6.9
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.5
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.270.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.9
    com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.6
    com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
    com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
    com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
    com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
    com.apple.security.quarantine   3
    com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
    com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
    com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
    com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
    com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.250.3
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.250.3
    com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
    com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
    com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
    com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
    com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
    com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
    com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
    com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
    com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
    com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
    com.apple.kec.pthread   1
    com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
    com.apple.kec.Libm  1

    EOF
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Kernel Panics can occur from many different things, so your goal is to weed things down to the culprit.

Here are some tips:

1. Make sure you're running the latest version of FL Studio as they often resolve crashing/memory issues, etc on newer revisions of software. There were others who mentioned having Kernel panic issues with Mojave and the update was suggested: https://www.image-line.com/fl-studio-download/
2. Run the Hardware Test on your system by restarting your computer with the D key held down (D for diagnostics). https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731
3. Listen for other clues such as overheating issues -- if the crash happens after you hear major fan noise, or after a hot day, or if you're doing intense work it may be related to overheating. The old systems will get dust and such in the fans and can overheat more easily. If you feel up to it you can open the bottom of the Mac mini and spray compressed air in the various areas - especially around the fan.
4. See if crashing occurs elsewhere as well -- if it's always when using FL Studio, target your attention there.
5. BACKUP! Make extra sure you've got good backups going on -- the first drive crash was the reminder, now you'll want to make extra sure going forward that you can recover from another potential crash.

*Note: Other potential causes for Kernel panics - Faulty or dirty fan, CPU/GPU issues such as on some of the MacBook Pros the thermal paste started coming loose and causing overheating, RAM issues, data corruption on the drive, application you're running has bugs. The data corruption on the drive is the least likely culprit as you've recently replaced the drive and I'm guessing reinstalled the system software fresh onto the new drive.*